# How to fix double layered text on python graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

My python graph has odd double layered text and as a beginner I don't know how to clean this up. How would this be done?

Thanks

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig1 = plt.figure(1)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 701, 100))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0.0, 3.7, 0.5))

frame1=fig1.add_axes((0.1,0.3,.8,.6))
m, b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
plt.plot(x, m*x + b, '-', color='grey', alpha=0.5) 
plt.plot(x,y,'.',color='navy',markersize=6)
plt.errorbar(x,y,xerr=0,yerr=yerr,linestyle="None",color='navy')
plt.ylabel('$Natural\ Log\ of\ Rate$',fontsize=17)
plt.grid(False)

frame2=fig1.add_axes((.1,.1,.8,.2))
s = m*x+b #(np.sqrt(4*np.pi*8.85E-12)/2.23E-8)*x
difference = y-s
plt.plot(x, difference, 'ro')
frame2.set_ylabel('$Residual$',fontsize=17)
plt.xlabel('$Time$ $(s)$',fontsize=17)
plt.savefig('mygraph')

plt.show()
```

Comment: While it is obvious that the plot doesn't look nice, it's not clear what you want instead. Which axes should be where? Should both graphs be in the same axes? Consider reading [ask] and provide a [mcve] (what is `x`, `y` and `yerr` here?).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to let matplotlib automatically position the subplots using `fig.add_subplot(211)`, where `211` means that on a grid of 2 rows and 1 column, the first (top) subplots shall be used.

Afterwards it's convenient to use the API methods to plot to an axes, `ax.plot()` instead of `plt.plot()`, and also setting all other labels and ticks using the API methods. This makes it easier to determine which elements belong to which subplot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 700, 100)
y = np.arange(0.0, 3.5, 0.5)

fig1 = plt.figure(1)

ax1=fig1.add_subplot(211)
m, b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)

ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 701, 100))
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(0.0, 3.7, 0.5))
ax1.plot(x, m*x + b, '-', color='grey', alpha=0.5) 
ax1.plot(x,y,'.',color='navy',markersize=6)
ax1.set_ylabel('$Natural\ Log\ of\ Rate$',fontsize=17)
plt.grid(False)

ax2=fig1.add_subplot(212)
s = m*x+b #(np.sqrt(4*np.pi*8.85E-12)/2.23E-8)*x
difference = y-s
ax2.plot(x, difference, 'ro')
ax2.set_ylabel('$Residual$',fontsize=17)
ax2.set_xlabel('$Time$ $(s)$',fontsize=17)

plt.show()
```

[image]